# Android Uploading image to ftp server not working

Tags: java, android, upload, ftp, ftp-client

Hey I am trying to upload an image to my ftp server but from some reason the connection isn't working and I can figure out why..

here is the connection code:

```
 public  void uploadingFilestoFtp() throws IOException {
    FTPClient ftpclient = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    boolean result;


    try {
        ftpclient.connect(host);

        result = ftpclient.login(username, password);

        if (result == true) {
            System.out.println("Logged in Successfully !");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Login Fail!");
            return;
        }
        ftpclient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        ftpclient.changeWorkingDirectory("/");

        File file = new File(imagePath);
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Upload file to the ftp serverresult = ftpclient.storeFile(testName, fis);

        if (result == true) {
            System.out.println("File is uploaded successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File uploading failed");
        }
        ftpclient.logout();
    } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            ftpclient.disconnect();
        } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using exactly the details of the ftp server but it doesn't seems to work

How can I get this mehod to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You are trying to make a network request from the UI thread. Android doesn't allow any network request from main(UI) thread. You need to create a class extending [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

```
public class UploadFileTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void > {

    public void onPreExecute() {

    }

    public void doInBackground(Void...unused) {
        uploadingFilestoFtp(); //Call your method here. Put necessary try-catch block.
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // do something when upload is done.
    }
}
```

Note that this `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` run on the UI thread. So you can do any stuff before or after the network call. Make the network call in `doInBackground()` method.

Check this answer [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/3857465)